# defining an iterator for BST

Tags: c, iterator, binary-search-tree

I need to define an iterator structure and method in C (for a BST), so far I realise that the iterator struct must have a pointer to a current node, and possibly a parent node. Is there anything else I should have in there, or that would be good to have?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the BST elements have a pointer to their own parent node? If not, you'll need a stack of parent node pointers.

Comment: I haven't implemented them with a pointer to a parent node,although I could if this would make life easier?

Comment: @Sarconi If it's a self-balancing sort of tree, use the stack of parent pointers -- it only needs to be as large as the maximum depth, and updating parent pointers in each node would make rebalancing more complicated.  If not, you may as well put a parent pointer in each node since in the worst case a stack could get very large.  Walking the tree is just as easy with either approach.